# Winforms derived combobox property two way binding

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, binding

I created custom ComboBox control and want to bind custom property "ActiveValue" to a DataSet. I do it in the way:

```
cboMyComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("ActiveValue", Me.dstDetails, "Table.CBOVALUE", True, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, ""))
...

Public Property ActiveValue As String
    Get
        Return _activeValue
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If _activeValue <> value Then
            _activeValue = value
            Me.Text = _activeValue
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

It retrieves value from DataSet, but it is unable to update. It doesn't matter what value I choose it simply is not updated. This property is simple text field. Tried to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on my derived ComboBox class, but it not helped. Could someone tell me where is the problem? Thanks

UPDATE:
found a bug in my class but Rex provided databinding write methods is also helpful, thanks for your time.

Comment: How did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, if you implemented that interface wrong, that could be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why as I cannot see your full implementation, but if you really want to force the databinding to write value back to object, try DataBinding.WriteValue(), so in your ComboBox class, do this at appropriate place (probably at some text changed event handler):

```
   theDataBinding = Me.DataBindings(theIndex) ' you may find the binding by the bound field name
   theDataBinding.WriteValue()
```